# how to resolve burn variables in the bootstrap xml

Tags: variables, bootstrapper, burn

One of my goals in creating the bootstrap project is to set a default log location.  I would like the location to be based on the local app data folder.  I cannot figure out how to reference the builtin Burn variable LocalAppDataFolder.  I have found information about how to reference these variables in code, but not in the xml.

The reference to the property looks like this:

```
 <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyInstaller.msi"  LogPathVariable="[LogLocation]" />
```

The property is set like this:

```
<Variable Name="LogLocation" Value="[LocalAppDataFolder]MyLogFolder\Setup" Type="string"/>
```

The log output shows:

> Initializing string variable 'LogLocation' to value
>   '[LocalAppDataFolder]MyLogFolder\Setup'

What am I missing to resolve [LocalAppDataFolder] ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal for the log output to show the un-formatted value, so that part looks correct. I think what you are missing is LogPathVariable should be specified without the brackets.

```
<MsiPackage SourceFile="MyInstaller.msi"  LogPathVariable="LogLocation" />
```